# SiteScope + log file monitoring

Tags: monitoring, logging

I have SiteScope monitoring log files for specific text. When that text shows up, an alert is triggered and an email is sent out. However, the email is sent out twice and I cannot figure out why.

Alerts are set to run for each log entry matched, but there is always only 1 new entry as I am manually testing it.

The alert messages are almost identical, save the time. The two show up in my inbox immediately, but there is a 5-10 minute delta in the time stamp on the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of OVO agent allows multiple multiple opcle programs, then there may be 2 running in parallel, they will both scan the same file and the alert would be duplicated.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. any way to prevent/limit that?

Comment: First, check the status of the OVO agents on the managed node:
`OPCAGT -status`

If there is only one Logfile Encapsulator running, try to:
Turn on the Duplicate Message Suppression Counter with the option "suppress identical output messages" ticked. So we can rule out the glitches on the side of the opcle itself.

Also, please tell me the version of HP Operations Manager that you're running, what operating system the agent is running and if it is a cluster node virtual machine.
They renamed and redesigned it so many times... 
I need to make sure, we're talking about the same thing :)